# Manual call for a method in knockout extender

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-datepicker

I couldn't find any working solutions for my problem, however I'm aware of it may be a trivial way to make it working but I can't figure it out.

I have an extender called liveEditor which switchs between a display text and an input where user can put a value. It works nice with inputs and textareas but I couldn't manage it with i.e. datepicker.

Here goes my code

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="liveEditor: Date">
  <span class="view" data-bind="text: Date, event: {click: Date.edit}">15.04.2016</span>
  <span data-bind="event: { click: Date.stopEditing }" class="ok"></span>
  <input value="15.04.2016" data-bind="datetime: Date, event: {blur: Date.stopEditing}" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
ko.extenders.liveEditor = function (target) {
    target.editing = ko.observable(false);
    target.edit = function () {
        target.editing(true);
    };

    target.stopEditing = function () {
        target.editing(false);

        //save
        this.saveModel(); //run a method on viewmodel
    };
    return target;
};

ko.bindingHandlers.datetime = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor,  allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var $el = $(element);

        if (ko.isObservable( value )){

            $el.data('kendoDatePicker').on('close', function(e,dataItem){
                // what should I write here to call a stopEditing method?
            });
        }
    }
};
```

It works when I click on OK-button.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

> what should I write here to call a stopEditing method?

The observable is available from `valueAccessor()`, so:

```
valueAccessor().stopEditing();
```

That will access it as of the time the event occurs. If it's important that you use the value as it was when `init` was called, you're closing over that in `avlue`, so it would be `value.stopEditing()`.

Two other alternatives for you (but I think I'd do the above):

- You could access the `events` binding from `allBindings` and then and grab its `blur` binding and call it
- You could trigger a `blur` event on the `input`

Comment: Thanks for replay. I had to send viewModel as well because I've got an error at saveModel method doesn't exist in "this" (in stopEditing function)